# Error Compiling Assets Rails 3.2.13

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, assets

When I go to my rails app in my browser I am getting the following error:

Error Compiling CSS Assets
ArgumentError: no time information in "2013-09-20T10:02:37-05:00"

I have been able to work around this error by clearing the cache and cleaning my assets and restarting Apache. However, I cannot do this anymore.

This is not my first Rails project, but this is the first time I have run into this error, and I cannot figure out how to get around this. I should also add that I have been developing the app for a week now, without this error. I have made no changes to my any of my assets.

I figured I'd add the error message from my logfile.

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15066ms

ActionView::Template::Error (no time information in "2013-09-25T12:55:42-05:00"):
 2: <html>
 3: <head>
4:   <title>JournalReview</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___63165616209989497_70158248592280'


Rendered vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (9.6ms)
```

Thanks.

Comment: So I think I caused the error my adding some functions to the Fixnum class of Ruby. I commented out the initializer code that contained the additional function, and that seemed to clear the issue. I need some math functions such as factorial and combinations for my app, and adding functions like 2.factorial and 3.choose 2, seemed like a good idea and keeping with Rubyisms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I had overridden the "!" operator to appear as the factorial notation used in math. I had tested this, because I had expected this to interfere with the false logic, I did not expect this to through an error in Time / Date.

Anyway, I removed that operator, from my module, and everything worked.